# Using wsdl 1.2 with ksoap2-android

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap2

I am using ksaop2-android to generate my web service,
and here is the wsdl i use: *http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL*

This is my code:

```
    String serviceUrl = "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL";
    String methodName = "GetCityWeatherByZIP";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/",
            methodName);
    request.addProperty("ZIP", "64101");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(serviceUrl);
    try {
        ht.call("http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityWeatherByZIP", envelope);
        if (envelope.getResponse() != null) {
            SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            System.out.println(soapObject.getProperty("ResponseText"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I can get correct response by this url:
*http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityWeatherByZIP?ZIP=64101*

However, my code give me the response like this:

*City could not be found in our weather data. Please contact CDYNE for more Details.*

It seems the argument was not been sent, which part could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD);

    request.addProperty("ZIP", "64101");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        .....


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

where

```
SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityForecastByZIP";
URL = "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx";
METHOD = "GetCityForecastByZIP";
NAMESPACE = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/";
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is "dotnet = true"

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I used some old code of mine in which I had used `dotNet=true`. Anyway, did it work for you now ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ht.call("http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZIP", envelope);
```

instead of:

```
ht.call("http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityWeatherByZIP", envelope);
```

Comment: I tried it, but still got the same response. It seems the argument was not been sent......

Comment: or at this line 
 SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
try to use envelope.bodyIn instead of getResponse

Comment: Thanks, the method name is wrong. But it still said invalid ZIP, so i think the argument was not sent still